# ArrayList shows null pointer exception even if instantiated

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting a null pointer exception when trying to set and write to an ArrayList of objects. According to the internet the most common cause is that the ArrayList is never instantiated but I still get the exception even though I instantiate it. See below code.

```
public class Invoice {

    private int invoiceNumber;
    private Date date;
    private int supplierCode;
    private double total;
    private ArrayList<InvoiceLines> lines;
    private String status;


    //getters and setters
    public ArrayList<InvoiceLines> getLines() {
        return this.lines;
    }

    public void setLines(ArrayList<InvoiceLines> lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    public void addLine(int lineNumber, int qty, int productCode, int invoiceNumber) {
        InvoiceLines il = new InvoiceLines();
        il.setinvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber);
        il.setlineNumber(lineNumber);
        il.setqty(qty);
        il.setproductCode(productCode);
        il.setStatus("insert");
        getLines().add(il);
    }

    // Servlet code

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session==null) {
        session = request.getSession(true);
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        session.setAttribute("invoice", invoice);

        ArrayList<InvoiceLines> lines = new ArrayList<InvoiceLines>();
        session.setAttribute("lines", lines);
    }

    Invoice invoice = (Invoice) session.getAttribute("invoice");
    session.setAttribute("invoice",invoice);
    ArrayList<InvoiceLines> lines = (ArrayList<InvoiceLines>) session.getAttribute("lines");
    session.setAttribute("lines ",lines);


    // gets the data from the request
    int qty = request.getParamater…;
    int productCode = request.getParamater…;
    int lineNumber = request.getParamater…;
    int invoiceNumber = request.getParamater…;

    if(request.getParameter("addLine")!=null) {
        invoice.setLines(lines); ////// null pointer exception!!!
        invoice.addLine(lineNumber, qty, productCode, invoiceNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because invoice is null, it has nothing to do with the ArrayList

Comment: How so? Can you elaborate? I do instantiate the invoice object.

Comment: Only if there is no existing session. Do you have a preexisting session?

Comment: Indeed, I never checked for the existing session and objects assigned to it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is being caused by `invoice` being `null`, rather than anything to do with the `ArrayList`.

This is likely to be because you have a pre-existing session. You are only assigning a new invoice to the session if there was no session already.

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
if(session==null) {
    session = request.getSession(true);
}
Invoice invoice = (Invoice) session.getAttribute("invoice");
if (invoice == null) {
  invoice = new Invoice();
}
session.setAttribute("invoice", invoice);

// Similarly for lines.
```

I'm not super-familiar with sessions, but it's not clear to me that you'd always need to set the attribute value again (as in, unconditionally call `session.setAttribute(...)`. You might be able to only set it when you create a new `Invoice`.